# Listed close reason is wrong in /tools?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons

Not really sure what is going here, but here is a picture:

[image]

The stated reason at the bottom is that it is too localized, but the only close vote is for off topic.

What is going on?

Comment: I think it was flagged for being too localized, but voted to close for being off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That that was me I'm afraid.

I meant to vote as either `Not constructive` or `Too Localised`, but got distracted at the last moment.

Either way I *did* mean to vote to close.

-=EDIT=-

To explain why there is also a `Too Localised` flag on the question, it is because low rep users cannot directly vote to close a question.  They can on the other hand flag it with a valid reason in order for a moderator to convert it to a close.

This is helpful from a moderation standpoint as it allows low rep users a similar, though less immediate, impact on getting questions closed.

In short a low rep **flagged** as `Too Localised`, and I **VTC'ed** as `Off Topic` (though I should have used `Too Localised`).

Comment: Then why does the vote not show up?

Comment: @soandos see my edit